# My OneNote 2013 will not sync with my SkyDrive on my new pc,

Tags: sync, onedrive, microsoft-onenote-2013

Good morning,  a little while back I learned about OneNote and really love this application, I was able to keep it on my laptop and sync it to my smart phone as well so I always had my info beside me.

Recently however, I got a new pc and upgraded to OneNote 2013, I have been so looking forward to getting it all synced up but now I cannot seem to sync my desktop folder with my Skydrive,  can you tell me what I am doing wrong OR if i need to change something in my internet options?

Thanks a mill
Sue

Comment: Could you please describe how does it behave? (error messages etc.)

Comment: ok, so firstly when I go into "Open" on the file button, it shows Open from Skydrive with a sign in option below it - when I click on it I get no respose at all, there is nothing here.

Comment: Also,  (sorry hit return too early there) when I click on the "Share" button, it has, Share Notebook, and below that is has in a highlighted bar, "To share this notebook, you wil lneed to put it on skydrive or sharepoint".

Comment: Did you get any resolution to this problem?